# Formatting a thesis summary chapter

Tags: formatting, titles

I'm trying to format my thesis summary title, but the result is not very appealing. Here's the code:

```
\chapter*{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering A very long thesis title about some very important stuff and a bit longer and a little more longer}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}
\begin{center}
    John Smith

    \large Summary
\end{center}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

I'm using the `report` documentclass. And the result is:

[image: a busy cat]

Doesn't look too bad, but the spacing between name and title is a bit too much. Can I somehow reduce that spacing for **only** this chapter?

Or alternatively, is there a better way to make a summary chapter?

Comment: This distance doesn't look to big :-). It can be reduced with ``\vspace<desired amount>} before your name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the name and the subtitle to the `\chapter*` command; adjust the dimensions in the definition of `\summary` until you're satisfied.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper,margin=1in}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\newcommand{\summary}[2]{%
  \chapter*{%
    \parbox{\textwidth}{%
      \centering
      #1\\[1.5ex]% the title and the separation
      \normalfont\normalsize
      #2\\[2ex]% the author and the separation
      \large Summary
    }%
  }%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Summary}%
}

\begin{document}

\summary{A very long thesis title about some very important stuff
         and a bit longer and a little more longer}
        {John Smith}

Some text follows

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Does'nt this obscure the intended markup? (i.e. formatting the thesis title as a `\chapter`, meshing the author name together with the summary heading.) Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Ruben This is for a special application.

Comment: For a collection of several theses in one document? (Or why would one code the thesis title into a `\chapter*`?)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a better way to include a summary. You can use the `abstract` environment and `\renewcommand` the `\abstractname`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=3.1415cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\preto\@title{\bfseries}}% bold thesis title
\makeatother

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Summary}

\title{A very long thesis title about some very important stuff and a bit longer and a little more longer}
\author{John Smith}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Summary}
\begin{abstract}
  \lipsum
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

The spacing here should be like what you were looking for by default.

[image: output]